# Implementing Non-static Ad Hoc Locks in Java

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am reading the book "Core Java I" written by Cay S. Horstmann and he mentions about the ad hoc locks as such in page 577:

> You will sometimes find “ad hoc” locks, such as

```
public class Bank
{
    
    private double[] accounts;
    
    private var lock = new Object();
    
    // . . .
    
    public void transfer(int from, int to, int amount)
    {
        synchronized (lock) // an ad-hoc lock
        {
            accounts[from] -= amount;
            accounts[to] += amount;     
        }
        
        System.out.println(. . .);
    }
}
```

> Here, the lock object is created only to use the lock that every Java
> object possesses.

As you know, locking is a mechanism that prevents other threads to execute specific code block. If the lock is not static (as mentioned in the code section above) any thread that has own its lock, and do not have any idea about the locks of the other threads. In other words, in order to perform the locks, locks shall be unique among all other threads. By this definition, shall lock be static?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's `static`, then just one lock exists for usage. If it's not `static`, then a lock exists per `Bank` instance for usage. Assuming that you know how `synchronized` works, you should know what the difference is now. You should decide `static` or not on how `transfer` is meant to be used, not by some fancy definition.

Comment: Note that the code doesn't even compile, as `var` isn't allowed for class members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lock like in your example is not static. The reason is that it is not a static value of the class - that would have the `static` modifier.

If a thread 'encounters' a `synchronized` block, the thread will try to acquire the referenced object. If none is provided, then the object containing the method will be locked. Such a lock is object specific, and is returned, when the thread leaves that code block.

Static locks can also occure, when the methods called are static themselves:

```java
public static synchronized void soSomething() {
   ...
}
```

In those cases, the `Class` object of the surrounding class is locked, which means that only one thread can ever access any method within a class that is `static synchronized`, even if the methods could logically be accessed simultaniously.

An 'ad hoc' lock makes sense, if a specific subset ob functionality is supposed to be locked simultaniously, but there are multiple such subsets, which should lock independent from each other, *or* if the lock should explicitly be hidden, so it is not locked/unlocked in an unintended way. 'Do not expose your locks' is a pro argument for using lombok's `@Synchronized` annotation for locks.

https://projectlombok.org/features/all